# Function to Evaluate Postfix Always Results in 1

Tags: c++, postfix-mta

Here are the functions involved in evaluating my postfix expression:

```
float postfixUtility::evaluatePostfix(string pexp)
{
stack<float> S;
int pexpLength = pexp.length();
for (int i = 0; i < pexpLength; i++)
{
    cout << pexp[i] << endl;
    if(pexp[i] == ' ' || pexp[i] == ',')
    { 
        continue;
    }     
    else if(isOperator(pexp[i]))
    { 
        float operand2 = S.top(); 
        //S.pop();
        float operand1 = S.top(); 
        //S.pop();
        float result = isOperate(pexp[i], operand1, operand2); 
        S.push(result);
    }
    else if(isDigit(pexp[i]))
    {   
        float operand = 0; 
        while(i<pexp.length() && isDigit(pexp[i]))
        {
            operand = (operand*10) + (pexp[i] - '0'); 
            i++;
        } 
        i--;
        S.push(operand);
    }
} 
return S.top();
}


bool postfixUtility::isDigit(char C) 
{
if(C >= '0' && C <= '9') 
{ 
    return true;
}
return false;
}


bool postfixUtility::isOperator(char C)
{
if(C == '+' || C == '-' || C == '*' || C == '/')
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}


float postfixUtility::isOperate(char operation, float operand1, float operand2)
{
if(operation == '+')
{   
    return operand1+operand2;
}
else if(operation == '-')
{
     return operand1-operand2;
}
else if(operation == '*')
{
     return operand1*operand2;
}
else if(operation == '/')
{   
    return operand1/operand2;
} 
}
```

The problem is that every time I run it, I get 1! Does not matter the input. I can put in "5 2 /" and get 1. It does not make sense to me and I have no clue why this is happening. If anyone can help me out that would be amazing as this assignment is due very soon!

Comment: Why are you commenting out the `S.pop()` lines? In other to give its exceptions guarantees, poping an element from `std::queue` is done in two separate step: 1) copy/move the element using `front()`, 2) remove the element using `pop()`. If you don't do the later, the same item will remain at the top of the stack until something else is pushed.

Answer (score 0):

You should pop stack after get top element in stack. std::stack::pop() only returns the top element of the stack, not the pop operation.

Change `float operand1 = S.top();` to

```
float operand1 = S.top();
S.pop();
```

and change `float operand2 = S.top();` to

```
float operand2 = S.top();
S.pop();
```